# Gray emoji on Chrome, Windows

Tags: windows

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0crQh.png

After uknown actions (my wife did something), In Windows 10 Emoji started to appear black and white in chrome (and other chromium-like browsers). Also the font has changed a bit too. In Mozilla, everything remains the same. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Your question does not seem to fit to StackOverflow. Move your question to SuperUser!

Comment: have you tried this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-start/color-emojifont-support-on-windows-7/8010df8b-c628-4d2d-8cad-24b7bec8c444